# Message: Trying to get property of non-object error in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
function status_message($status){
    $ci = & get_Instance();
    $message = $ci->db->select('message')
                  ->get_where('messages', array('name' => $status))
                  ->row()
                  ->message; // this is line 2137

        return $message;

}
```

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: helpers/custom_helper.php

Line Number: 2137

Comment: Which of these is line no 2137?

Comment: check the the comments in code

Comment: Ok, so you can `var_dump($ci->db->select('message')->get_where('messages', array('name' => $status))
                  ->row());` and check what you get as a result?

Comment: got this...   object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#22 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(36) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(47) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["row_data"]=> NULL }

Comment: Can you add formatted result in your post? As of now, it is unreadable.

Comment: `["num_rows"]=> int(0)`. The query doesn't return anything. You can't do `->message` on a non-existing object. Check the result from the query before trying to use it.

Comment: @M.Eriksson can i use default value instead of this array? i mean i want to put empty string or something else instead of this array

Comment: Yes, I often use the null coalescing operator in my CI project when I try to access a specific property from `row()`. `row()` can only return an object or null.

Comment: @mickmackusa can you show me how I can achieve this? i'm new to php

Comment: @Noman https://3v4l.org/Cst7i